# How do I reference a library I wrote within the same project?

Tags: javascript, module, typescript

Say I wrote a library using typescript. Following [tslint](https://github.com/palantir/tslint) as a guide, my folder structure looks something like:

```
src
   build
   classes
   interfaces
   typings
      packagesIUseInLibrary
      tsd.d.ts
   tsd.json
   tsmvc.ts
test
   examples
      ...
   typings
      tsd.d.ts
   tsd.json
```

tsmvc.ts is the "face" of the library. It contains stuff I need to expose to the outside world.

```
export * from  "./classes/helper/ApiParser";
export * from  "./classes/helper/ApiRepository";
export * from  "./classes/helper/DefaultApiParser";
export * from  "./classes/helper/List";
export * from  "./interfaces/data/DataRepository";
export * from  "./interfaces/model/Ctor";
export * from  "./interfaces/model/Model";
```

So far, so good. Now I need to consume the library, from within the test folder, but it seems the only thing I can do is:

```
import {DataRepository, Model} from "../../../../src/tsmvc";
```

Is there any way I can fix my project so I can end up using this syntax:

```
import tsmvc = require("tsmvc");
```

Instead of relative paths?

I've tried generating the .d.ts file by switching:`"declaration": true` in my `tsconfig.json`. This results in a `tsmvc.d.ts` with exactly the same contents as `tsmvc.ts`. Then I tried referencing it as below:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../src/build/tsmvc.d.ts"/>
import tsmvc = require("tsmvc");
```

Which gives me: `Cannot find module tsmvc.`

But my package.json contains:

```
{
  "name": "tsmvc",
  "typescript": {
    "definition": "./src/tsmvc.ts"
  }
}
```

So according to: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/247, it should work.

Edit:

I suspect it's something similar to:

> test\typings\tsmvc\tsmvc.d.ts:

```
/// <reference path="reference/used/in/library"/>
declare module "tsmvc" {
    import main = require("index");
    export = main;
}
```

However I need to reference index from the /src/ directory, and I've discovered that "Import or export deceleration in an ambient module deceleration cannot reference module through relative name."

Answer (score 0):

> Instead of relative paths?

Only with the *latest* (unstable) version of TypeScript. You would need to configure `baseUrl` https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039